# .bashrc file only has 'source /etc/profile' in it

Tags: bash

my .bashrc file only has the line `source /etc/profile` in it, how do i get it back to normal? I know I misconfigured something but I don't know how to change it back to normal. Any help would be great.
Thanks

Comment: Try copying it back from `/etc/skel`: `cp /etc/skel/.bashrc ~`.

Comment: Its still the same, in `/etc/skel/.bashrc` it says the same thing

Comment: @Atavixion what is your OS/distro?

Comment: I recently switched from Manjaro to Arch using Archfi, ik this dosent normaly happen because ive done this before, but now idk

Comment: Should I just reinstall arch?

Comment: Why would reinstalling an OS make it magically change something? If `/etc/skel/.bashrc` contains `source /etc/profile` then that's what you'll get

Comment: Because I know i changed someting in archfi, I've done this afew times and none of those times have this happened

Comment: Well, first, if its the very first line of your .bashrc... then... it should not really matter. Then... well... you know... the .bashrc of your own directory is here in order for you to put what you want. No more, no less. So... feel free to delete this line. Then... if something very wrong happens... you'll get time (and means) to investigate further. In no case reinstalling is needed. BTW, I only used this instruction when chrooting. So... could well be some relief of your install.

Comment: @MC68020 thankyou so much I found that I could chance a few things in the /etc/profile to make it look better. Glad to know I don't have to reinstall it.